# Unable To Install pyttsx3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am using python 3.7 And Pycharm. I want to install pyttsx3.  When I try it through command prompt it show that it is installed successfully but when I initialize it it gives me error which I have posted in brief in [Unable to use pyttsx3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684859/unable-to-use-pyttsx3) . So When I try to install through pycharm it gives me this error. Here Is An Image Also - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWz3G.png

````
     command: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-agmtbp8j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\comtypes'
         cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\comtypes\```
``` ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\comtypes\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-agmtbp8j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Include\comtypes' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWz3G.png
````

Comment: First as indicated upgrade pip version 20.1.1 to version 20.3.1.  Second, check the logs for full error report as indicated.

Comment: @itprorh66 My pip version is 20.3.2

Comment: Not according to your error message see "WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.3.1 is available."

Comment: @itprorh66 So should I uninstall my pip 20.3.2 and install pip version 20.3.1 or should I just downgrade my pip version ?

Comment: Before you do that ensure you don't have two versions of python installed

Comment: @itprorh66 ok I don't have two versions of python installed but should I downgrade to pip version 20.3.1

Comment: @itprorh66 I downgraded pip to 20.3.1 and installed pysstx3 v 2.90 but i got error

Comment: Did you determine if you have more than one version of python running?  Did the error message include the warning about running the wrong version of pip?

Comment: @itprorh66 No only one pip version is running and No the error msg did not include wrong version of pip

Comment: If you try to import it in your app does it still give you the error ```ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes37.dll)```?